# Infinite login lightdm ArchLinux

Tags: authentication, archlinux, xfce

Just installed arch linux base as descibed. all works perfect.

Got installed xfce:
pacman -S xfce4 xfce4-goodies lightdm lightdm-gtk-greeter

well, I stuck in loop login with lightdm. Once I typed login and password, it blinks and returns me to login screen again.
If I just run startxfce4 - it works
Any suggestions?

Comment: just stried SLIM login shell, - the same result - bring me back to login. I dont want to use GDM since it depends on gnome stuff

Comment: Do you have free memory on disk?

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this one:

```
rm ~/.Xauthority
```

I had the same issue using [SDDM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SDDM)

--update--

It helped me. Go to System Settings -> Display and Monitor. Check the main screen. I should change to laptop screen. Apply changes. It works for me now after reboot.